# R: Get current row minus previous row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that has two rows and the rows have labels as shown below. I want to calculate the absolute change and percent change using the first two rows. How can do it using dplyr?

```
                  a          b
previous          5         10
current           4          5
absolute change  -1         -5
percent change  -20%       -50%
```

Comment: base R, if I may: `d <- sapply(df, diff) ; p <- paste0(d / df[1,] * 100, "%") ; rbind(df, "absolute change" = d, "percent change" = p)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably find that `dplyr` isn't particularly well suited to this task, because tidyverse packages such as `dplyr` are designed to work best with *tidy* data frames (one column per variable, one observation per row).

If you are presenting your data to others in a summary table, having rows at the bottom containing absolute and percentage change is fine, but a data frame isn't really the correct structure to hold a summary table.

For instance, each column in a data frame must be a vector containing data of the same type. This means that if you want percentage signs in the last row, you can only do this if you change the columns to character variables. This means you could no longer carry out any calculations with the data.

In other words, adding summary rows is not really what data frames are for, and the end result is certainly not a *tidy* data frame, so it's not a natural thing to do in `dplyr`.

What you are asking for is certainly possible using dplyr, but it's a bit convoluted:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  add_row(summarise(., across(everything(), diff))) %>%
  add_row(summarise(., across(everything(), ~100 * last(.x)/first(.x)))) %>%
  `rownames<-`(c(rownames(df), "absolute change", "percent change"))
#>                   a   b
#> previous          5  10
#> current           4   5
#> absolute change  -1  -5
#> percent change  -20 -50
```

As an aside, if you transpose your data frame it *is* in tidy format, and you can easily add the summaries as new columns. It's almost just as easy to transpose your data, add summary columns and then trsnspose back:

```r
as.data.frame(t(df)) %>%
  mutate(`absolute change` = current - previous,
         `percentage change` = scales::percent(`absolute change` / previous)) %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame()
#>                      a    b
#> previous             5   10
#> current              4    5
#> absolute change     -1   -5
#> percentage change -20% -50%
```

Note that, as mentioned above, the columns in this second version are *character vectors*.

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(a = 5:4, b = c(10L, 5L)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c("previous", "current"))

df
#>          a  b
#> previous 5 10
#> current  4  5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>